# How do you get the command callback of a menu entry in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to obtain the exact object associated with the command proprety from a tkinter menu entry. (for example to call it)

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> m = Menu()
>>> m.add_command(command = lambda: None)
>>> m.entrycget(1, 'command')
'2914238139136<lambda>'
>>>
```

Using `entrycget` returns me the funcid. Can I get the actual callback from the funcid, or do I need to use another method entirely?

Comment: I don't think you can get the actual Python callback - but you can indirectly call it via `m.invoke(index)`.

Comment: Why do you need the function object

Comment: yes i guess this function is concidered in tk without return, so it isno need to get a reference to it